# Is it possible to filter statements by Team in Tin Can?

Tags: tin-can-api

I'm recording statements to the LRS and in each of those statements I always set the "Team" property.

I know I'm able to filter those statements by verb, activity and many other parameters [as described here](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI.md#723-getstatements).

However, I can't find a way to filter statements by Team (which is a property of Context).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to use identified groups (a group with an IFI) as the value of the "team" property and then request statements using the "related_agents" query parameter. Note that this will include statements where that identified group is also the "actor" or in any of the other positions accepting a Group/Agent object, so you'll still have to post process them. As far as I know there is no way to request based on an unidentified group since they aren't considered the same group across requests.

There is no way to specifically request only statements based solely on the "context.team" property.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have added team property to context.extension property. You should not add properties that are not allowed, otherwise, you might have issues in future.

Regarding querying by team or any other extension property, it cannot be done as per standard xAPI Spec. However, your LRS could allow you to do that. e.g. You can get an LRS like [GrassBlade LRS](http://www.nextsoftwaresolutions.com/grassblade-lrs-experience-api/) or Learning Locker and get it customised to add more filtering options.